# Jquery attr method returns undefined for a checked checkbox

Tags: jquery

For the above checkbox

```
document.getElementById("checkbox1").checked // -> returns true
```

But

```
var byAppr = document.getElementById('checkbox1').value;
$(byAppr).attr('checked') // -> returns undefined
```

I am testing this in firefox 3.6

Comment: which version of jquery are you using?

Comment: var byAppr = document.getElementById('checkboxName').value;
$(byAppr).attr('checked') // -> returns undefined

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Use one of the following:

- `$('#checkbox1').prop('checked')` - in jQuery 1.6+, **usually the way to go**
- `$('#checkbox1').is(':checked')` - all jQuery versions, but slower
- `$('#checkbox1').attr('checked')` - NOT in jQuery 1.6 - but in 1.6.1 and <=1.5, **don't use it**

Also, in cases where you already have the DOM element available directly (e.g. `this` in an event handler bound to the field), use `this.checked` instead of `$(this)` with one of the methods above!

Answer (score 2):

You're selecting based on value. I think you want:

```
var byAppr = document.getElementById('checkbox1');
$(byAppr).attr('checked')
```

Comment: Actuall this is exactly what i am doing ...that is resulting in undefined return value
 
    var byAppr = document.getElementById('checkboxName').value;
    byAppr = '#'+ byAppr;
    $(byAppr).attr('checked');

Comment: You're still including `.value` at the end of the first expression. If you exclude that it should work as expected.